# On macOS Sonoma, is there a keyboard shortcut to peek at the location of an aerial screen saver?

Tags: macos, screensaver, sonoma

The new macOS Sonoma has aerial screen savers—similar to Apple TV—and one of the options is to shuffle through all of them.

On Apple TV, you can tap the up arrow 2x to peek at the location of the current screen saver.

Is there a similar way to peek the location of a screen saver on macOS Sonoma?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no keyboard shortcut for this but you can check a screensaver's location in System Settings > Screen Saver.